# Replacing --cluster-config with --profile in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Recent version of Snakemake (v5.10.10) says [cluster configuration has been deprecated](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration-deprecated) and recommends to use [profiles](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles) instead. However, I don't see any documentation on how to go about this.

How do I convert the following cluster config ([example](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration-deprecated) used in snakemake doc) into profiles?

```
{
    "__default__" :
    {
        "account" : "my account",
        "time" : "00:15:00",
        "n" : 1,
        "partition" : "core"
    },
    "compute1" :
    {
        "time" : "00:20:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just found the same question in [bioinformatics stackexchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/11454/7237). No good answer yet though.

Comment: Two years later still no clue how to do this in an un-deprecated way. However "deprecated" though, it's still working when you use an extra cluster configuration file, so I guess they are somehow aware that there is no good workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using this link you should be able to find the right profile for you. I agree the documentation is not amazingly clear how to go about migrating.

https://github.com/snakemake-profiles/doc

Comment: I already use [slurm profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm) that you linked, but I'm not sure how to integrate cluster-configs into those profiles.